# What is the least number of brackets you can delete to make sequence of brackets balanced

Tags: algorithm

For example: we have sequence "(()(()))", then the answer is 0 (well, it is balanced brackets sequence)

Let's say that we have such sequence: "))(((", then optimal number to delete would be 5 (there is no other way to make it balanced apart from deleting all of them)

If we have such sequence: "())(()", then the answer is gonna be 2 (let's delete the third and the fourth ones)

Comment: By the way, input sequence can't be longer than 100000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you are one possible solution:

1. start from the begin with a variable `count = 0` that counts the "open" brackets and `needed = 0` that are the number of brackets you need to balance
2. every time you find a `(` add 1 to `count`
3. every time you find `)`:
   if `count == 0` then you need an open brackets before, so you do `needed = needed += 1`
   else, decrease the number of open brackets found `count = count - 1;`
4. at the end, add the number of remaining open brackets, to the needed, because you need `count` final closing brackets: `needed = needed + count`

at the end:

```
count(string)
    count = needed = 0
    for i = 0 to string.length
        if string[i] == '('
            count = count + 1
        else if string[i] == ')'
            if count == 0
                 needed = needed + 1
            else 
               count = count - 1
    return count + needed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push open characters into the stack and when you encounter a closed character, if the stack is not empty pop an element from the stack if balanced, else increase count. After iterating, add the remaining chars present in the stack.

```
private static int getCount(String input) {
    char open = '(';
    int charsToDelete = 0;
    Stack<Character> characterStack = new Stack<>();
    for (int i=0;i<input.length();i++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        if (ch == open) {
            characterStack.push(ch);
        } else {
            if (!characterStack.isEmpty()) {
                char pop = characterStack.peek();
                if (pop == '(') {
                    characterStack.pop();
                } else {
                    charsToDelete++;
                }
            } else {
                charsToDelete++;
            }
        }
    }
    while (!characterStack.isEmpty()) {
        characterStack.pop();
        charsToDelete++;
    }
    return charsToDelete;
}
```